# Oracle Error - Cast is not valid

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

I am able to populate a datatable via .NET from Oracle but when I use LINQ expression, I get this error..

[image]

Linq expression is:

```
var hello = dataSet
  .AsEnumerable()                
  .Where(x => ((x.Field<string>("ID") == "DK-076_1") && 
              ((x.Field<string>("AREA") == "FIELD"))))
  .Select(r => r.Field<double>("XSURF"))
  .ToList();
```

`ID` is `VARCHAR2(20)` , `AREA` is `VARCHAR2(20)` and `XSURF` is `NUMBER` in Oracle table.

Comment: Have you done any work to narrow it down to a specific field? (Note that if you've already got a dataset, this is after you've fetched the result, surely... so the Oracle part is mostly irrelevant.) My *guess* is that you might want to use `decimal` instead of `double`, but you should be able to investigate that yourself. You should also update your question to show the stack trace of the exception including the details, but just as text rather than as a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe `decimal` is more apropiate to a `NUMBER` field, although i'm not sure that is causing the `InvalidCastException`

Comment: Not every *Oracle's* `Number` can be cast as `double`  http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featSafeType.htm#i1008428

Comment: Definitely the error is when i use a "double" field. I picked a different column which is varchar2 = string type and it works fine! I don't know what to use when the column is NUMBER type in Oracle.

Comment: @user7157732 look at XSURF column length and precision in schema. probably it will either be `int`, or `decimal`

Comment: Is the Precision giving you problems ? Maybe you can retrieve the XSURF as datatype OracleDecimal, an later change precision an cast to **double**. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15968334/212987)

Comment: I don't think its the precision but type defined in linq as double.Thnx for the link. @AndrewR

Comment: @Pikoh yeah you are right. should be decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final Linq:

```
 var hello = dataSet.AsEnumerable()                
            .Where(x => ((x.Field<string>("ID") == "DK-076_1") && ((x.Field<string>("AREA") == "DUKHAN_FIELD"))))
             .Select(r => r.Field<decimal>("XSURF")).ToList()
             .Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item)).ToList();
```